# In what paper was the shrinkage parameter introduced to the nelder-mead simplex direct search algorithm?

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, na.numerical-analysis, linear-programming

I have read lots of papers referencing a 4th shrinkage parameter when talking about the Nelder Mead Simplex method. However, I cannot see any shrinkage parameter in the flow chart of the original paper (Nelder and Mead 1965). When was this parameter introduced?

I am sure there are only 3 parameters in the Nelder Simplex method, I have the paper right in front of me!! Or have I lost my mind.